# Add line from excel VBA without the running file

Tags: vba, excel

I just need the IF line that says that if he tries to open the file that runs the code(Trying to open himself) then skip it.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
Sub Auto_Open()

        Dim SrcBook As Workbook
        Dim fso As Object, f As Object, ff As Object, f1 As Object

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set f = fso.Getfolder("C:\test\new")
        Set ff = f.Files

        For Each f1 In ff
                Set SrcBook = Workbooks.Open(f1)
                Range("A2:IV" & Range("A20").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
                Range("A20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                SrcBook.Close
        Next
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to thank someone because thier answer worked you can tick the checkmatrk next to their answer and/or up vote. See the helpcenter [Someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 1):

Taking your code as is, you could add the following If-statement to the For Each-loop:

```
    For Each f1 In ff
       If StrComp(f1.Name, ActiveWorkbook.Name, vbTextCompare) <> 0 And _
          InStr(1, f1.Name, "~") = 0 Then
            Set SrcBook = Workbooks.Open(f1)
            Range("A2:IV" & Range("A20").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
            Range("A20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SrcBook.Close
        End If
    Next
```

The first condition prevents opening the current file itself, the second condition also skips the temporary file that Excel creates on opening a file.

**Reworked Code**

Just as an aside, I would refactor and expand the code as follows:

```
Sub Auto_Open()
On Error GoTo Err_
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim Folder As Object
    Dim Files As Object
    Dim File As Object

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Folder = fso.Getfolder("C:\Temp\Excel")
    Set Files = Folder.Files

    For Each File In Files
        If StrComp(File.Name, ActiveWorkbook.Name, vbTextCompare) <> 0 And _
           InStr(1, File.Name, "~") = 0 Then

            With Workbooks.Open(File.Path)
                Range("A2:IV" & Range("A20").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
                Range("A20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                .Close
            End With
        End If
    Next

Exit_:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Set Files = Nothing
    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_:
    Resume Exit_
End Sub
```

A few remarks:

- Error handling to **ensure** that even in the case of an error **`ScreenUpdating`** is **switched back on again**. Otherwise you could leave your application not refreshing to the user in case of an error.
- Separate line for each variable - easier to grasp
- More explicit variable names. First and foremost, code should be **easy to read**, not easy to type.
- **`With`**-block for the local variable to make it's scope explicit. Saves the local variable SrcBook as well.
  Here it might be argued that the name of that variable helped understanding the problem and should better be kept.
- Explicit setting the object variables to **`Nothing`**. Might be paranoid, but as a SOP it can help to avoid all kind of weird issues in some cases.

Since it might be challenging to get the intent of the code in the **`With`**-block is, I would even go further and extract that block into a new method with a intent-revealing name to make things clearer. The name could be along the lines of `CopyProductListFromFile`.

Comment: Nice effort, but... Your `With` block confuses more than it helps! The only thing you're using it for is `.Close`. Also, though this is [not properly documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193498%28v=office.14%29.aspx), `ScreenUpdating` reverts to true automatically when macro execution ends. Try it. As for setting these FSO objects to `Nothing`, I'd like to see one example where not doing that leads to weird behaviour. I've never seen one, or heard of one, ever. Also, clear variable names are good, but beware, `File` is also a FSO object class.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett Sure, you're right with your issues (I was not aware of the ScreenUpdating behavior - thx!). Just the `With` block for me is not about having some kind of short-hand syntax, but to explicitly provide a scope for an object. Setting all the object variables to `Nothing` is meant as a safe operating procedure, that I am following now for ages just to be explicit and on the safe side. As I wrote, it's probably just paranoid. :)

Comment: Scope for *which* object?

Comment: The scope of the implicit object the `With` ... `End With` spans and whose members can be accessed by starting directly using the `.TheMember` syntax. BTW, for objects to be fully flexible it is convenient to have some kind of property `Self` so that this implicit object can be passed as an argument to a method. I find this pattern rather elegant to use (in most cases).

Comment: But the only member of the implicit object you access that way is `.Close`. The four other lines could just as well be outside the `With` block. They're not in this "implicit scope" at all. For example, the `Range` aren't explicitly qualified.

Comment: That's just true for the explicit access to the object's members. But the "thing in Excel" that is standing behind that object (i.e. the Workbook) is needed for the duration of the whole block. The first line after `Workbooks.Open(...)` refers implicitly to the newly opened workbook, since it became the active workbook by opening it.

Comment: Ah, now I see what you mean. You're relying on the fact that `ActiveWorkbook` is the default workbook — and that the workbook opened by `Workbooks.Open` sets that default. In my opinion, relying upon default behaviour is not an improvement — certainly not in terms of clarity — over setting an explicit reference like the OP did with `Set SrcBook = ...` (though OP didn't fully use that afterwards).

Comment: Well in that regard, there is no difference between an excplict variable and a With-block. That is the default behaviour the very original code relied on. I would not do that either (being notoriously paranoid regarding those things). More discussion on that via Twitter/DM.

Answer (score 1):

```
 If Not ThisWorkbook.FullName = f1.Path Then
            Set SrcBook = Workbooks.Open(f1)
            Range("A2:IV" & Range("A20").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Activate
            Range("A20").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            SrcBook.Close
 End If
```